# How do I retrieve information from an API using Java?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, localhost

I have zero experience with web development, so I am really sorry if this question wastes your time, but I really need help. I have currently set up a website hosted in "localhost" using spring MVC. I am not sure if this is an issue. If it is, then I would like to know how to tell Java(particularly in the GreetingController class that was created by Spring MVC) to change the domain where the website is being hosted.

Anyways, what I need to do is to pull information from EventBrite's API and store it in Strings. I have searched tirelessly for an answer to this problem, but I could not find it.

Edit:

Ok, so I have written the following code after visiting https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/#initial

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    EventIDs eids = restTemplate.getForObject("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/", EventIDs.class);
    log.info(eids.toString());
                                        }
```

}

However, I dont know how to enter the key to get access to the API. I keep getting an HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized Exception. The API itself doesnt say anything

Comment: You might check out a library such as Apache HttpComponents. Reading through their tutorial should get you started.

Comment: I think that your question probably should be about how to deploy your site files to a web server which is accessed at a particular domain. How to do this depends on the web server that you are using.  Each web server has it own deployment methods.

Comment: I didn't realize that there are really two questions here. Every API has documentation.  Try looking here: https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/introduction

Answer (score 0):

Well I hope I can help you to understand a bit more about programming(Doing source code) and deploying(putting the executable in a container or server)

1. Once you put the executable on the container or server, it will autoamtically grab the IP address of the server(meaning as well the domain name).At this point what really matters is targeting the url of your current program. For example your local  controller is http://localhost:8090/gretting, once you put your file in the server it will take the host address and the port, meaning that to reach your program you will have to make a get request to http://1.2.3.4:8080/greeting. This aplies to both IP address and domain name.
2. To be honest I dont even know what EventBrite is, but they use REST architecture, so you might aswell learn how to transfer data with consuming rest from a web siter, here is a small tutorial to help you start with it https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/